# bash loop with pattern and quote characters

Tags: bash, loops, echo, quotes

```
DESTINATION="example_substitute.txt"

echo "$DESTINATION"

DESTINATIONPATH="/home/example/test"

echo "$DESTINATIONPATH"

ARRAY=('EXP1' 'EXP2' 'EXP3 EXP4' 'EXP5 EXP6')

for n in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do

    (

    echo "$n"

    echo "sudo grep -RiIl --exclude-dir={_themes,_styleguide,_templates,_static,_RFCs,_glossary,_scripts,_blockdiag,_Definition} ' $n ' | xargs sed -i 's/ $n / :term:`$n` /g' ./*.rst" >> $DESTINATIONPATH/$DESTINATION

    )

done
```

I want to combine from the array my grep command and put it in $DESTINATIONPATH/$DESTINATION

as a newbie echo "$n" bring the right Expression.
the second echo strugles with the quotes:

it SHOULD be:

```
sudo grep -RiIl --exclude-dir={_themes,_styleguide,_templates,_static,_RFCs,_glossary,_scripts,_blockdiag,_Definition} ' EXP1 ' | xargs sed -i 's/ EXP1 / :term:`EXP1` /g' ./*.rst

sudo grep -RiIl --exclude-dir={_themes,_styleguide,_templates,_static,_RFCs,_glossary,_scripts,_blockdiag,_Definition} ' EXP2 ' | xargs sed -i 's/ EXP2 / :term:`EXP2` /g' ./*.rst

sudo grep -RiIl --exclude-dir={_themes,_styleguide,_templates,_static,_RFCs,_glossary,_scripts,_blockdiag,_Definition} ' EXP3 EXP4 ' | xargs sed -i 's/ EXP3 EXP4 / :term:`EXP3 EXP4` /g' ./*.rst

sudo grep -RiIl --exclude-dir={_themes,_styleguide,_templates,_static,_RFCs,_glossary,_scripts,_blockdiag,_Definition} ' EXP5 EXP6 ' | xargs sed -i 's/ EXP5 EXP6 / :term:`EXP5 EXP6` /g' ./*.rst
```

Comment: What does it mean "strugles with the quotes"? The output is valid, is there something wrong with it? What exactly? (except, that it's missing `EXP5 EXP6`, I guess that's a copy+paste thing, right?) And `xargs sed ... ./*.rst` makes no sense - you could just remove `grep` and `xargs`.

Comment: sorry for my bad English:

the output SHOULD be before like:

sudo grep -RiIl --exclude-dir={_themes,_styleguide,_templates,_static,_RFCs,_glossary,_scripts,_blockdiag,_Definition} ' EXP1 ' | xargs sed -i 's/ EXP1 / :term:`EXP1` /g' ./*.rst

if you look on 

' EXP1 ' | xargs sed -i 's/ EXP1 / :term:`EXP1`

but it breaks and only if I take out the '  and ` I got a wrong result.

The important thing for me is to get this: ' EXP1 ' | xargs sed -i 's/ EXP1 / :term:`EXP1`

Comment: You will want to escape the backticks, otherwise they are expanded as a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) (which in your case likely raise an error since `$n`'s value isn't a command)

Comment: As a sidenote, in general generating dynamic code is not the best use of your time and you'd better have a some static code (either a function or a script file) that can be parametrized and call it with your variables

Comment: $n is here mentioned as a value (e.g. EXP1)

Comment: Yes, no worry with that. What I meant is that \`$n\` in this context is parsed as "run the command `$n` and replace me by its output". `EXP1` isn't a command, so not only does \`$n\` get replaced by the empty string, but in addition it raises an error (I guess `EXP1 : Command not found`)

Comment: And as mentioned this could be fixed by escaping the backticks, using \\`$n\\` instead of \`$n\`

Comment: hopefully understanding you right Aaron I changed the line as follows:

echo "sudo grep -RiIl --exclude-dir={_themes,_styleguide,_templates,_static,_RFCs,_glossary,_scripts,_blockdiag,_Definition} \'$n'\ | xargs sed -i 's/ \$n\ / :term: \`$n`\ /g' ./*.rst"  >> $DESTINATIONPATH/$DESTINATION

the script terminate/break and there is no output in the file

Comment: Not really related to your original question, but why do you run your loop body in a separate child process?

Comment: you get with your proposal:

sudo grep -RiIl --exclude-dir={_themes,_styleguide,_templates,_static,_RFCs,_glossary,_scripts,_blockdiag,_Definition} \' EXP1 \' | xargs sed -i 's/ $n\  ....

Comment: Check [this ideone test](https://ideone.com/Ng7LpL) where I've escaped the backticks, isn't the output what you're expecting?

Comment: Also note that if you plan to copy/paste or eval those commands you'll run into the same problem with the backticks : they will be parsed as command substitution and raise an error and be replaced by the empty string before the sed command is executed, so if you really want to carry on generating code (which I insist you shouldn't) you will most likely need to double-escape them (e.g. write 3 backslash before a backtick, so that a first parse will translate it to a backslash before a backtick, which will be parsed a second time as a literal backtick rather than a command substitution)

Comment: As a last note, use @username if you want to catch someone's attention, you were lucky I came back to this question; we're not using it to reply to you because as the writer of the question we're commenting on you're automatically notified

Comment: this is great @Aaron ! This is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that pairs of backticks ( `` `...` `` ) are parsed by the shell running your script as [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), so the shell tries to execute the value inside as a command and replace the pair of backticks and its content by the output of the command. I assume you don't have an `EXP1` command, so it raises an error and is replaced by the empty string, which breaks your `sed` command in your output.

To achieve your expected output, you should simply escape the backticks (no need to do anything with the single-quotes when they are found inside a double-quoted string) :

```
echo "sudo grep [...] ' $n ' | xargs sed -i 's/ $n / :term:\`$n\` /g' ./*.rst" >> $DESTINATIONPATH/$DESTINATION
```

However I assume you want this text to be later interpreted as a command, whether you're going to execute the file you store them into, copy/paste them into a shell or any other way. If that's the case, and if EXP1 and other values of `$n` shouldn't be interpreted themselves as commands at that point, you will actually need to double-escape the backticks :

```
echo "sudo grep [...] ' $n ' | xargs sed -i 's/ $n / :term:\\\`$n\\\` /g' ./*.rst" >> $DESTINATIONPATH/$DESTINATION
```

In this command we've got an escaped backslash followed by an escaped backtick, which will be interpreted by your current script and have it output the following command in which we find an escaped backtick :

```
sudo grep [...] ' $n ' | xargs sed -i 's/ $n / :term:\`$n\` /g' ./*.rst
```

That way when you execute this command, the escaped backtick will be interpreted as the actual character rather than being parsed as command substitution, raising an error as there is no such command and breaking your `sed` command.

As you can see, this is all rather complicated, which is why I urge you to stop generating code and instead store your code template into a script file or function and simply generate call to these.

For instance with the following script, let's call it do_the_thing.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo grep [...] ' $1 ' | xargs sed -i 's/ $1 / :term:\`$1\` /g' ./*.rst
```

Note that I've replaced the `$n` by `$1`, which is a reference to the first parameter this script will be called with.

At that point could replace your current script's loop body by `/path/to/do_the_thing.sh "$n"` and not worry about the effects of double-interpretation because the actual code will only be interpreted once, when the call you generated will be executed.

Note that you would need to make the script executable (`chmod +x /path/to/do_the_thing.sh`) and that you could use a relative path (e.g. `do_the_thing.sh "$n"`) if the calls you generate are to be executed from the same directory the `do_the_thing.sh` script is located in.

Moreover, with the simplicity this extra script brings, you could question the need for a generating script at all. After all, executing the 5 commands you currently try to generate would become as easy as

```
for param in 'EXP1' 'EXP2' 'EXP3 EXP4' 'EXP5 EXP6'; do
    /path/to/do_the_thing.sh "$param"
done
```

Comment: this is great @Aaron ! This is amazing!

Comment: @PierreGronau it's not much really, glad I could help ! I don't think you can upvote answers at your current reputation but consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if you consider it solved your problem, it's a simple way of showing gratitude and it helps future users with the same problem picking an appropriate solution.